# ORBEON XForms: Filtering values in the repeated grid

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have the following XML:

```
<Details Category="a">
    <Code>1</Code>
    <Quantity>46.8</Quantity>
</Details>
<Details Category="a">
    <Code>4</Code>
    <Quantity>50</Quantity>
</Details>
<Details Category="a">
    <Code>7</Code>
    <Quantity>20</Quantity>
</Details>
<Details Category="b">
    <Code>8</Code>
    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
</Details>
```

I would like to create 2 repeated grids, one per category

My binds are the following:

```
<xf:bind id="Details-bind" ref="Details" name="Details">
    <xf:bind id="Category-bind" ref="Category" name="Category"/>
    <xf:bind id="Code-bind" ref="Code" name="Code"/>
    <xf:bind id="Quantity-bind" ref="Quantity" name="Quantity" />
</xf:bind>
```

and the first repeated grid:

```
<fr:grid id="First-grid" repeat="true" bind="Details-bind"
                                template="instance('Group1-template')"
                                 min="0" >.....
```

How can I get in the "First-grid" only values where Category="a"? I have to use binds because I have various calculations.

Updated with the repeated grid template:

```
<xf:instance id="Group1-template" >
    <Details>
        <Code/>
        <Quantity/>
    </Details>
</xf:instance>
```

Comment: I guess that you do this outside of Form Builder?

Comment: @ebruchez complex objects I do outside of Form Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `First-grid` has `bind="Details-bind"`, so on that bind, if you want it to list the elements with `Category="a"`, you'll want to put:

```
<xf:bind id="Details-bind" ref="Details[@Category = 'a']" name="Details">
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because the filter is working. The mentioned solution affects the insertion of a new row in the repeated grid. I updated my question with the template.

Comment: @klgr So you're all good with this, right? (I'm not sure to understand your last comment about insertion.)

Comment: The filter is OK, but I cannot add a new row in the repeated grid when I click the + Button. Most Probably because of the  "Details[@Category = 'a']" in the ref property. It is working without the filter.

Comment: In the "Group1-template" I added <Category>a</Category>. Adding of a new row is working now. So everything is working now. Thanks @avernet.